Looking for the Title of a specific horror movie
Hey everyone I've been trying to find out the name of a certain movie I've been looking for for a while; maybe someone can assist:
Things I remember:

Couple moves into an old mansion. Movie is in color though I think it was made in the 70s - 80s. The couple has no children as far as I remember
There was an old lady around (maybe landlady or neighbour or something)
As time progressed, the wife began to notice the house was haunted and she would sometimes see a scene of someone hanging in their garden / backyard (maybe the old lady herself)
Husband started to act differently as the movie progressed; more aggressive towards his wife
For some reason I think the maid was trying to seduce the husband (somewhat like American Horror Story) but not sure

I believe this movie was a "Made for TV" Horror and hopefully someone can figure it out and let me know
Thanks a lot!

The Conjuring had somewhat similar events (an old lady who was a possessed spirit, a tree in the back yard that someone was hanging from but was only visible to one person), but that was made in 2012.

Yes Conjuring is a bit too new. I saw this movie back in the early 90s when I was a kid living in the Caribbean. Every year @ Halloween it would be shown on TV.

Does Burnt Offerings (1976) sound familiar?

Perhaps it is Burnt Offerings, a 1976 film (based on a 1973 novel). A family moves into an old mansion for extended vacation. One stipulation is that the mother of the owners will stay as well, but she is in an upstairs room and never comes out - they just leave meals for her in the hallway.
The wife becomes obsessed with caring for the house (which gives the house energy).  I don't remember a maid, but it  has been a long time since I've seen it. It used to be shown on American television pretty frequently.

I suggested this possibility in a comment (above) :). Also it came out in 1976, not 1973.

Thanks for the date correction. Yes, I thought of Burnt Offerings and was looking it up when you added your comment. If you would like to submit an answer, I will remove mine.

Thanks for the suggestion Trish / Leatherwing. Throughout my research, "Burnt Offerings" does seem the closest to what I remember. I will give it a look and see if it's that

@Mitch: Was this the correct film?
